# How can you make your C# code pretty?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

Hi I was wondering if there is any tool that automatically make your source code pretty, like adding comment templates for each method, take care of spacing, tabs and whatnot?

Thanks

Comment: There are lots: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ 
Try CodeMaid and GhostDoc, for a start.

Comment: Visual Studio and other IDEs are built exactly for this purpose (Visual Studio does *all* of what you just requested). I think this question should be closed though. Tooling is a contentious issue, pretty is subjective, etc.

Comment: GhostDoc is great for auto documenting, http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx, VisualStudio can do the rest

Comment: I know how you can make your C# code [pretty...](http://studiostyl.es/schemes/my-little-pony)

Comment: Check things like ReSharper and StyleCop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio, out of the box, has some formatting options, via `Edit->Advanced->Format Selection` and `Edit->Advanced->Format Document`.  These primarily fix spacing, tabs, and similar issues, but won't add comments.  It also has the ability to add XML doc comment stubs, but only for a single method at a time (type `///` above a method, field, property, constructor, or type).

Tools like Resharper perform full [Code Cleanup](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_formatting.html), which can do many of these things automatically.

Comment: Is Resharper free yet?

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio, the default hotkey for formatting code is `ctrl+k+d`. By typing in `///` a comment template will be inserted based on context.

For example, typing in `///` above a method with the signature `static void Main(string[] args)` will give the following:

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="args"></param>
static void Main(string[] args)...
```

Comment: Note: my version of VS is `ctrl+E,D`